# Sleep until a certain condition is met [c++]

Tags: c++, boost, sleep, thread-sleep

so I have a simple networking code, where it checks if an atomic priority queue, which can be pushed from several different threads, is empty or not. If it is not empty, it will take that value and do some operation with it.

```
    for (;;) {
        REQUEST currentRequest; // REQUEST is an enum
        
        bool isEmpty = m_RequestsQueue.GetFrontAndPop(currentRequest);

        if (!isEmpty)
        {
            // some unrelated networking operations
            ...
        }            
    }
```

The problem with the above code is that my infinite loop is CPU intensive. I can not afford to add stuff like `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));` to reduce the CPU load, as some REQUEST that might be added to the queue might need to be handled right away.

How can one add a "sleep until condition is met" in a thread? I don't mind using boost if needed.

In the above example, the condition would be that the size of my array is greater than 0 for example

Thanks!

Comment: This is merely the inescapable penalty for chasing the elusive lock-free atomic unicorn fairy. Locking implies getting blocked until the blocking condition goes away. Old-fashioned mutexes and condition variables is how you don't burn CPU time waiting for things to move forward. If you want to block until your queue is ready to go then use a mutex and a condition variable. "Sleep until a condition met" is the literal definition of a mutex and a condition variable. It's even a part of their name! Anyone seeking the fame and prestige of atomicity must exchange it for a CPU bonfire.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for the reply. I'm kind of new to networking so it's not a problem I've faced many times before. I didn't know mutex could be used like this. I will take a look at the documentation :)

Comment: So there's  no misunderstanding: my mentions of a "condition variable" is not just casual English prose. It refers to a specific object in the C++ library, just like "mutex" does.

Comment: ohh I see : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable
thank you again!

Comment: Well, Stackoverflow is definitely about asking questions. That's what Stackoverflow is all about, and I feel obligated to state that for the record, but, having said that: Stackoverflow is not a replacement for a C++ textbook, which has a complete discussion of this and other topics, and fully explains what this, and all the other related topics are, in a logical, easy to follow, and understandable manner. If you'd like to learn about them, that's where you'll go. I use cppreference myself, but not to learn anything, but look up stuff I already learned. From a textbook.

Comment: I would highly recommand reading **C++ Concurrency in action** book. A must if you are serious about multithreading in C++.